# Magento - Multi Websites, Multi Currency

Tags: magento

I have a website that has USD set as the base currency. This domain has a main page (index.php) where the customer can click/select either products for men or for women. They will then be forwarded to either: www.domain.com/men or www.domain.com/women. When the customer checkouts, the payments is processed through PayPal in USD.

My customer is now asking me to allow the user to be able
to check out using CDN currency.

This is what I have done so far.....

In the Magento Admin Panel:

1) Created 2 new product categories for the men and women for cdn purchases:
   Men-Cdn / Women-Cdn (some products won't be available in Canada).

2)  Created new website called "MyDomainCdn".

3)  Created 2 new stores:
    MyDomain Men Cdn Store / MyDomain Women Store

4)  Created 2 new store views:
    MyDomain Mens Cdn Store View / MyDomain Womens Cdn Store View
    and assigned the appropriate catalog to each one.

In the File Manager:

1) Created a new sub-domain called cdn.mydomain.com.

Am I on the right track? If so, what would be my next step,
or is there a tutorial to walk me through this part?

I am totally stuck on what to do next.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might not need separate categories after all. Each product can be disabled for individual websites, see the Websites tab on product edit page.

Go to *System > Configuration > Web*. In the top left corner change the scope control to your new website, the following changes will then only apply to it and not the whole of Magento. In the Secure and Unsecure sections change the Base URL to `http://cdn.mydomain.com/`.
You'll probably have an SSL certificate for transactions. Unless you have the rare wildcard type it won't work for sub-domains. Go buy a second certificate to match the domain you put in 'Secure' section.

While still in *System > Configuration* go to *Currency Setup*. The scope is still limiting  changes to the new site. Change the display currency and allowed currencies too if that makes sense.

I'm not sure what you're doing with File Manager. The intention is for `cdn.mydomain.com` to lead to the exact same directory as does `www.mydomain.com` which normally happens anyway. Instead edit the `.htaccess` file, add this bit before any other rewrites.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cdn.mydomain.com 
RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:cdn]
```

The run code ("cdn") will be what you put as the store code in *System > Manage Stores*.